# export sql data in cvs format

Tags: php

I have a table name tblstuden. It contains ids studentname, rollnumberm and classname. I want to download this data in CSV format. How is it possible?

I can upload the data into the table by CSV file. To upload the code is below. It's working for me. But now I want to download the data in CSV format.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $row = 1;
$file1 = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file = fopen($file1, "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 8000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
       $data[$c];}
    echo $data[0];

    $name = $data[0];
    }

fclose($file); 
?>
```

Comment: You're not moving or storing the uploaded file, so how would you like to download it again?

Comment: my data in the table can be stored useing the above script... i mean i can import the .cvs file ....but now i want to download the file... how is it possible?

Comment: if the records are on your db, you can do a query then store it in a variable in csv format.

Comment: how? is it possible/ sephoy08?can u provide me code?

Comment: sure. i posted it below.

Comment: @user1397999 I don't see any code that handles importing; the only thing happening here is an uploaded file being read. As soon as the names are printed and your script exits, the uploaded file is lost. You have to store the data, for example using a database and inserting the data in it, or using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\AppServ\www\registration\page\class.php on line 63

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\registration\page\class.php:5) in C:\AppServ\www\registration\page\class.php on line 67

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\registration\page\class.php:5) in C:\AppServ\www\registration\page\class.php on line 68

Comment: .:show me you code where you got this error.

Comment: <?php

if(isset($_POST['csvsubmit']))
{

$getRecord = mysql_query("SELECT id, studentname, rollnumber, classname FROM tblstuden");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getRecord )) {
$csvFile .= $row['id'].",". $row['studentname'].",". $row['rollnumber'].",".$row['classname']."\r\n";
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition:attachment; filename="."testCSV.csv");

echo $csvFile;



}
?>

Comment: <tr><td>Download CSV</td>
<td><input type = "" name = ""/></td>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type = "submit" name = "csvsubmit" id = "csvsubmit" value= "cs submit" /></td></tr></table>

Comment: .:this should be working fine unless you have a header() above the codes or you have an error on your db connection

Comment: no.. i had not included the header file in connection ...... how to deal with that?.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a csv file using this code.

```
$getRecord = mysql_query("SELECT id, studentname, rollnumber, classname FROM tblstuden");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getRecord )) {
$csvFile .= $row['id'].",". $row['studentname'].",". $row['rollnumber'].",".$row['classname']."\r\n";
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition:attachment; filename="."testCSV.csv");

echo $csvFile;
```